# regex with uppercase words and dash

Tags: regex, preg-match, uppercase

Given text strings such as these:

> wikiradio 27/09/2012 - LE QUATTRO GIORNATE DI NAPOLI raccontate da Ida
>   Gribaudi
>
> wikiradio 10/04/2013 - DAG HAMMARSKJOLD raccontato da Susanna Pesenti

I am working at a regular expression to match only the **UPPERCASE WORDS** of the strings (i.e. "LE QUATTRO GIORNATE DI NAPOLI" and "DAG HAMMARSKJOLD").
My code is this:

```
$title = $_GET["title"];
if (preg_match_all('/\\b(?=[A-Z])[A-Z\' ]+(?=\\W)/',$title,$match)) {

process matched portion...
```

It works almost always, but when the $title string includes *apostrophe+space* or a *dash*, it doesn't.
For example, uppercase words in these two titles are not matched.

> wikiradio 11/02/2014 - L'ABBE' PIERRE raccontato da Giovanni Anversa
>
> wikiradio 22/12/2015 - JEAN-MICHEL BASQUIAT raccontato da Costantino
>   D'Orazio

What am I missing?

Comment: I wonder can't you just take all the characters after the first dash, then stop at the first whitespace followed by a lowercase. That's as simple as `/- .*?(?= [a-z])/`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sZ8mR1/1).

Comment: That's an interesting workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this may works for you:

```
\b[A-Z].*?(?= [a-z])
```

[Regex online demo](https://regex101.com/r/aD3vA6/2)

**Legenda**

```
    \b         # regex words boundary [1]
    [A-Z]      # any single Uppercase letter
    .*?        # Any char repeatead zero or more in lazy mode
    (?= [a-z]) # matches when the next 2 chars are a space and any single lowercase letter

[1] regex word boundary matches between a regex word char '\w' (also [a-zA-Z0-9_]) 
    and a non word \W ([^a-zA-Z0-9_]) or at start/end of the string 
    (just like '^' and '$')
```

**Code demo** [on ideone](http://ideone.com/LvFHOF)

---

**Update**

An updated version that works using a white list of chars (we can't know it's all the possible one)

```
(?m)\b[A-Z][A-Z '-]*(?= |$)
```

The online demo of the [updated version](https://regex101.com/r/aD3vA6/3)

Comment: Will this work if there are no lowercase letters after the uppercase words?

Comment: @Barmar: see if the updated version can satisfy your case and thank you for your observation